# How to write queries where there are more than 2 conditions to extract info in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables as below

```
guides    users     offers      reservations     manager_crm_issues
id        id        id          offer_id         issuable_id
user_id   username  guide_id    issuable_type    issuable_type
```

What I Would like to extract is

```
guide.id,
guide.username,
manager_crm_issues.count(issuuable_id)
```

The issuable_type's distinct values are {Reservation, Offer, Guide}, and it corresponds to issuable_id.
i.e. if issuable_type = 'Reservation' then the issuable_id = reservation.id

Question is, I Would like to count all the issues happened on Guide, and Guide is linked to Offer, Offer is linked to Reservation.

```
SELECT 
a.guideId,
a.guideName,
count(case when cr.issuable_type = 'Reservation' and cr.issuable_id = a.rID THEN cr.id else 0 END),
count(case when co.issuable_type = 'Offer' AND co.issuable_id  = a.offerId THEN co.id else 0 END),
count(case when cg.issuable_type = 'Guide' AND cg.issuable_id  = a.guideId THEN cg.id else 0 END)
FROM
(SELECT
g.id AS guideId,
u.username AS guideName,
o.id as offerId,
r.id as rId
FROM guides g
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = g.user_id
INNER JOIN offers AS o on o.guide_id = g.id
INNER JOIN reservations AS r on r.offer_id = o.id) a
INNER JOIN manager_crm_issues cg ON cg.id = a.guideId
INNER JOIN manager_crm_issues co ON co.id = a.offerId
INNER JOIN manager_crm_issues cr ON cr.id = a.rId
group by 1,2
```

I tried to join tables like above, but the outcome seems inaccurate.
Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do it in two steps: (1) do a `select` with a `join` to get guideid together with guidename. (2) add a `GROUP BY`  combined with `count(*)`.

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is related to your issue because you do not say what the issue is but this does not do what you think it does:

```
count(case 
    when cr.issuable_type = 'Reservation' and cr.issuable_id = a.rID THEN cr.id 
    else 0 
END),
```

`count` counts not nulls so your query will count everything. What you want is

```
count(case 
    when cr.issuable_type = 'Reservation' and cr.issuable_id = a.rID THEN cr.id 
    else null 
END),
```